# 'django' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.(module error)

Tags: python, django, cmd, command-line, path

I have freshly installed python version 3.9 and it shows up in my CMD (command prompt),
but when I try to install django via command
**pip install django** (also tried sudo doesn't work either)
[command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fq9ZF.png)

but when I try to check my version via
**django --version**
[command line screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AYS5.png)

I have already tried to configure my environment path variable added every possible path in it.
[Environment path variable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8158.png)

P.S : I **don't want to create virtual environment** please don't suggest me that the same thing happen's there too. I have been stuck for many days with this problem if anybody actually know how to solve it **please help**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me clear the point that you tried using **sudo** in your windows machine, I believe that you used Administrator CMD or Administrator Power-shell.

Let's get to the point, from your screenshot it appears you already have the Django library installed in your machine but you are checking django version the wrong way.

You can check the version by using the below command:

```
python -m django --version
```

**OR**

```
pip freeze
```

*which will show you all python libraries versions.

please make sure to change python to python3 if this is what you are using, and do the same thing for pip as well

as an optional step you can try to create a project using below command

```
django-admin startproject testing-project
```

I hope this help you!, happy coding.